# Display records in a grid control (asp.net / vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, repeater

I am a newbie to the .net developing world.
I want to display a set of records on my asp.net page.

On a grid control (gridview, repeater etc), I want to display the list of sales people and the clients that they represent.

This is how it needs to look on my asp page:

```
Employee ID: 123456
Name:  John
Last Name: Smith
Email: johnsmith@abc.com
Phone: 201-123-4567

Client - 1
ClientID: 11111111
Client Name: XYZ Company
Client Contact: John Q Public
Client Phone: 201-222-3333

Client - 2
ClientID: 2222222
Client Name: Widget Company
Client Contact: George Williams
Client Phone: 201-333-4444

Client - 3
ClientID: 3333333
Client Name: Acme Products
Client Contact: Steve Mason
Client Phone: 201-444-3333
```

My sql query is something like:

```
Select sales.firstname, sales.lastname, sales.email, sales.phone sales.clientid from sales

select client.id, client.name, client.contact, client.phone from client, where sales.clientid = sales.clientid
```

The code would loop for all sales records

How would my syntax be structured?

Answer (score 0):

Following examples should help you.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0380__Data-Binding/DataBindingtoGridViewC.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

you'll need to change the query accordingly though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`. In this handler, you have to obtain the reference of `Repeater` control and bind the `dataSource` of client table for associated employee id.